# What does a DependencyReplicator.xml file look like?

Tags: tfs, build

I am trying to get started using Dependency Replicator http://www.codeplex.com/tfsdepreplicator. There is no documentation in place and therefore no example of a DependencyReplicator.xml file which I need in order to take my experiment further. Can anyone using Dependency Replicator supply a demo .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

In the buildtype create a DependencyReplication.xml file and use something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DependencyReplication  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.readify.net/tfsintegrator/dependencyreplication/20060725">
  <TeamProject TeamProject="AcmeAnvils" RootFolder="$/AcmeAnvils">
    <Dependency TeamProject="AcmeAnvils" BuildType="AcmeAnvilsContinuousBuild" >
      <File Source="Release/AcmeAnvils.Common.dll" Destination="$/AcmeAnvils/AcmeAnvil_Services/AcmeAnvils.Common.dll" />
      <File Source="Release/AcmeAnvils.Common.dll" Destination="$/AcmeAnvils/Dogfood/Dependencies/AcmeAnvils.Common.dll" />
    </Dependency>
  </TeamProject>  
</DependencyReplication>
```